# Null Pointer Exception to a RecyclerView that was defined

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I defined my recycler view and I'm still getting a null pointer exception when I try invoking methods on it, but it was working before

My layout is activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

My java MainActivity.java(on create)

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}
```

**FULL LOGCAT**:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.atry, PID: 31310
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.atry/com.example.atry.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3115)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3258)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.atry.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3095)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3258) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)

Comment: Can you share you full LogCat so people can look at the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

My main activity file was duplicated into **activity_main.xml** and **activity_main.xml(v28)**. Meanwhile, the two files do not correspond.
So my **MainActivity.java** was choosing **activity_main.xml(v28)** which wasn't the intended layout file

I just copied everything in **activity_main.xml** and I pasted it in **activity_main.xml(v28)**

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that `findViewById()` is called only after the layout has been inflated and set as content view using `setContentView()`.

Comment: It is:         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your issue

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);    
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```